# Xcode assistant editor disabled

Tags: xcode, uiviewcontroller, interface-builder

[image: Snapsjot]

I have a view controller in IB with a controller class linked to it, however, I cannot link any outlet to it neither the "Automatic" button is enabled, any idea why is this happening?

I have created a new storyboard and new classes, same story.
What could possibly be the problem?

Comment: I'm experiencing the same problem occurring in one of my projects time to time, and I still can't figure out what makes it break, and neither why does it start working again sometimes. It's a mystery. Tried cleaning, building, running, restarting Xcode - nothing seems to fix the problem, and then it suddenly starts working again one day, and then it breaks again another day. This completely prevents me from linking controls in Storyboard with my Swift source code, which is a deal-breaker, because if you can't link them, you can't work with them. The only sure solution is to not use Storyboard.

Comment: Just found one way to make it work for me -- rename the offending ViewController and update the "Class" field in the Storyboard to use the new name. Then it immediately starts working.

Answer (score 3):

I see same issue from time to time in different projects
Most times cleaning derived data manually and cleaning build folder via shift + command + K resolves this issue